# Direct Product and Quotients/Factor groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A, B \le G$ subgroups and $N \unlhd G$ a normal subgroup of $G$, then of course
\begin{align*}
 AN/N \cdot BN/N & = \{ aN \cdot bN : aN \in AN/N, bN \in BN / N \} \\
                 & = \{ abN : aN \in AN/N, bN \in BN/N \} \\
                 & = \{ abN : a \in A, b \in B \} \\
                 & = (AB)N / N.
\end{align*}
But what if $AB \le N_G(B) \cap N_G(A)$ and $A \cap B = 1$, then $AB = A \times B$. Do we then have
$$
 AN / N \times BN/N = (A \times B) / N 
$$
i.e. $AN/N \cap BN/N = \{ N \}$ and $AN/N \unlhd AN/N \cdot BN/N, BN/N \unlhd AN/N \cdot BN/N$?

Also if we switch our view and consider external direct products, then $A \times B$ would be a set of tupels, and so $N$ must be such a set, but on the left we have a set of tupels of the form $(aN, bN)$, but $N$ is a set of tupels, so $aN$ would not make any sense, rather maybe using $(a,1)N$ instead, so that the equality turns into an isomorphism. I am also a little bit confused with the notations, for example if $N \le A, B$, what should
$$
 A/N \times B/N \ge AB / N
$$
mean? Is this meaningful at all? Or
$$
 AN / N \cdot BN / N \ge (A \times B) / N
$$
if $A \cap B = 1$?

Comment: Hint: Consider $G$ to be an (Abelian) group of order $4$ with each non-identity element of order $2$. Then $G$ has $3$ cyclic subgroups of order $2$. Let $A,B$ be two of these, and let $N$ be the remaining one.

Comment: Then $G = AN = BN$ and $G = A\times B$, so that $(A\times B) / N = G / N \cong C_2$ and $AN/N \times BN/N \cong C_2 \times C_2$. By the way, was my first computations about the product correct, and what about the other relations, do they hold?

Comment: Remark: Please note that in my other relations I have no equality!

Comment: How could $A/N$ and even the bigger set $A/N \times B/N$ be a subgroup of $(A\cap B)/N$, to me as $A\cap B \le A$ we would have $(A\cap B)/N \le A/N$????? In my last sentence I mean the internal direct product.

Comment: How is $AB / N \le A/N \times B/N$ possible, and how could that be a subgroup of $(A \times B)/N$? Internally we have $AB / N = A/N \times B/N$ as $AB / N = A/N \cdot B/N$ by my first computation, but externally I cannot make sense of it? Also how is $AB / N$ a subgroup of $(A \times B)/N$, you mean the external direct product? But what is $N$ then, a set of tupels or a subgroup $N \le A \cap B$?

Comment: Or do you mean $(A \times B) / (N \times N)$ as external direct product?

Comment: Okay, so you mean $A \times B$ externally, but how is $N \le A \times B$ then, do you mean $N \cong N \times \{1\}$ or do you mean $N \times N$, just writting $(A \times B) / N$ makes no sense to me...